# How to use C++ functions correctly in Unreal Engine?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am trying to use [this ProjectPointToNavigation](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/AI/UNavigationSystem/ProjectPointToNavigation/index.html) through the following line:

```
bool navResult = GetWorld()->GetNavigationSystem()->ProjectPointToNavigation(HitResult.Location, NavLocation, TeleportFadeTimeExtent);
```

However, the method `ProjectPointToNavigation` is deprecated [with this function](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/NavigationSystem/UNavigationSystemV1/ProjectPointToNavigation/1/index.html)

My question is, how can I re-write my above code to use the newest `ProjectPointToNavigation` function?

I tried the following:

```
 bool navResult = UNavigationSystemV1::ProjectPointToNavigation(HitResult.Location, NavLocation, TeleportFadeTimeExtent);
```

The above code shows me the following error:

> 'UNavigationSystemV1::ProjectPointToNavigation' ambiguous call to overloaded function

Sorry if my question is simple, I am new to Unreal Engine and still learning its development (in my first stages)

**UPDATE:**

I tried the following (in the `header` class):

```
UPROPERTY()
class UNavigationSystemV1* NavSystem;
```

in `.cpp` class:

```
bool navResult = NavSystem->ProjectPointToNavigation(HitResult.Location, NavLocation, TeleportFadeTimeExtent);
```

its still didn't work, I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __cdecl UNavigationSystemV1::ProjectPointToNavigation(struct FVector const &,struct FNavLocation &,struct FVector const &,struct FNavAgentProperties const *,class TSharedPtr)" (__imp_?ProjectPointToNavigation@UNavigationSystemV1@@QEAA_NAEBUFVector@@AEAUFNavLocation@@0PEBUFNavAgentProperties@@V?$TSharedPtr@$$CBUFNavigationQueryFilter@@$00@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl AVRCharacter::UpdateDestinationMarker(void)" (?UpdateDestinationMarker@AVRCharacter@@AEAAXXZ) Explorer    E:\Unreal Projects\Explorer\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\VRCharacter.cpp.obj   1

Any guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 5):

In your `<Project Name>.Build.cs` file, `PublicDependencyModuleNames` should have `NavigationSystem` added. This will correct your linker error.

With regards to accessing the navigation system pointer itself, even if you got you got your code to work it would crash, as when you access `NavSystem` it will be null.

Instead call the following to get a pointer to the new nav system and project:

```
const UNavigationSystemV1* navSystem = NavigationSystem::GetCurrent<UNavigationSystemV1>(this);
bool navResult = navSystem->ProjectPointToNavigation(HitResult.Location, 
  NavLocation, TeleportFadeTimeExtent);
```

You'll need to `#include "NavigationSystem.h"` at the top of your implementation file.